# SQL - Grouping rows based on the conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, row-number, coalesce

I'm trying to group rows when it starts with 1 and has consecutive 0s, and stop grouping once it meets another 1 or 2.

Here is an example: (column 'group' is what I expect to see)

```
+-----+------+-------+
| seq | data | group |
+-----+------+-------+
|   1 |    1 |     1 |
|   2 |    0 |     1 |
|   3 |    0 |     1 |
|   4 |    0 |     1 |
|   5 |    2 |       |
|   6 |    2 |       |
|   7 |    1 |     2 |
|   8 |    0 |     2 |
|   9 |    0 |     2 |
|  10 |    1 |     3 |
|  11 |    0 |     3 |
|  12 |    0 |     3 |
|  13 |    2 |       |
|  14 |    0 |       |
|  15 |    0 |       |
|  16 |    0 |       |
|  17 |    0 |       |
|  18 |    0 |       |
|  19 |    2 |       |
|  20 |    2 |       |
|  21 |    1 |     4 |
|  22 |    0 |     4 |
|  23 |    0 |     4 |
|  24 |    0 |     4 |
|  25 |    2 |       |
|  26 |    2 |       |
|  27 |    0 |       |
|  28 |    1 |     5 |
|  29 |    0 |     5 |
|  30 |    0 |     5 |
|  31 |    0 |     5 |
|  32 |    1 |     6 |
|  33 |    0 |     6 |
|  34 |    0 |     6 |
|  35 |    0 |     6 |
|  36 |    0 |     6 |
|  37 |    2 |       |
|  38 |    0 |       |
|  39 |    0 |       |
|  40 |    0 |       |
|  41 |    0 |       |
|  42 |    0 |       |
|  43 |    0 |       |
|  44 |    0 |       |
|  45 |    0 |       |
|  46 |    2 |       |
|  47 |    2 |       |
|  48 |    2 |       |
+-----+------+-------+
```

I've tried using coalesce to make it possible, but this is what I've got:

```
select seq, data, coalesce((select sum(data) +1 
                           from mytable pre 
                           where pre.seq <= mytable.seq and pre.data = 1),0) as s1
from mytable
```

```
+-----+------+-------+
| seq | data | group |
+-----+------+-------+
|   1 |    1 |     2 |
|   2 |    0 |     2 |
|   3 |    0 |     2 |
|   4 |    0 |     2 |
|   5 |    2 |     2 |
|   6 |    2 |     2 |
|   7 |    1 |     3 |
|   8 |    0 |     3 |
|   9 |    0 |     3 |
|  10 |    1 |     4 |
|  11 |    0 |     4 |
|  12 |    0 |     4 |
|  13 |    2 |     4 |
|  14 |    0 |     4 |
|  15 |    0 |     4 |
|  16 |    0 |     4 |
|  17 |    0 |     4 |
|  18 |    0 |     4 |
|  19 |    2 |     4 |
|  20 |    2 |     4 |
|  21 |    1 |     5 |
|  22 |    0 |     5 |
|  23 |    0 |     5 |
|  24 |    0 |     5 |
|  25 |    2 |     5 |
|  26 |    2 |     5 |
|  27 |    0 |     5 |
|  28 |    1 |     6 |
|  29 |    0 |     6 |
|  30 |    0 |     6 |
|  31 |    0 |     6 |
|  32 |    1 |     7 |
|  33 |    0 |     7 |
|  34 |    0 |     7 |
|  35 |    0 |     7 |
|  36 |    0 |     7 |
|  37 |    2 |     7 |
|  38 |    0 |     7 |
|  39 |    0 |     7 |
|  40 |    0 |     7 |
|  41 |    0 |     7 |
|  42 |    0 |     7 |
|  43 |    0 |     7 |
|  44 |    0 |     7 |
|  45 |    0 |     7 |
|  46 |    2 |     7 |
|  47 |    2 |     7 |
|  48 |    2 |     7 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

I want to stop grouping once it meets 1 or 2, could you help me figure this out? Thanks

++

I have a similar task, which is to group from bottom to top but with a slight different conditions.

I need to group data when it starts with data '2', and close the group when it meets 1 or 2 but need to include them within the group too (0 or 1). Below is the expected output.

> ```
> +-----+------+-------+
> | seq | data | group |
> +-----+------+-------+
> |   1 |    1 |    11 |
> |   2 |    0 |    11 |
> |   3 |    0 |    11 |
> |   4 |    0 |    11 |
> |   5 |    2 |    11 |
> |   6 |    2 |    10 |
> |   7 |    1 |       |
> |   8 |    0 |       |
> |   9 |    0 |       |
> |  10 |    1 |     9 |
> |  11 |    0 |     9 |
> |  12 |    0 |     9 |
> |  13 |    2 |     9 |
> |  14 |    0 |     8 |
> |  15 |    0 |     8 |
> |  16 |    0 |     8 |
> |  17 |    0 |     8 |
> |  18 |    0 |     8 |
> |  19 |    2 |     8 |
> |  20 |    2 |     7 |
> |  21 |    1 |     6 |
> |  22 |    0 |     6 |
> |  23 |    0 |     6 |
> |  24 |    0 |     6 |
> |  25 |    2 |     6 |
> |  26 |    2 |     5 |
> |  27 |    0 |       |
> |  28 |    1 |       |
> |  29 |    0 |       |
> |  30 |    0 |       |
> |  31 |    0 |       |
> |  32 |    1 |     4 |
> |  33 |    0 |     4 |
> |  34 |    0 |     4 |
> |  35 |    0 |     4 |
> |  36 |    0 |     4 |
> |  37 |    2 |     4 |
> |  38 |    0 |     3 |
> |  39 |    0 |     3 |
> |  40 |    0 |     3 |
> |  41 |    0 |     3 |
> |  42 |    0 |     3 |
> |  43 |    0 |     3 |
> |  44 |    0 |     3 |
> |  45 |    0 |     3 |
> |  46 |    2 |     3 |
> |  47 |    2 |     2 |
> |  48 |    2 |     1 |
> +-----+------+-------+
> ```

I've used the similar approach of @shawnt00 's answer and below is what I got.

It gives what I expected to see, but I want to avoid left outer join if possible. Is there any ways to make this query clean?

```
with g1 as (
    select *,
        count(case when data = 2 then 1 end) over (order by seq desc) as grp
    from mytable
), g2 as (
    select *,
        count(case when data > 0 then 1 end) over (partition by grp order by seq desc) as grp2
    from g1  
)
select curr.seq, curr.data, curr.grp, 
       CASE WHEN curr.data = 1 AND next.grp2 = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE curr.grp2 END AS grp2
from g2 curr left outer join g2 next on curr.seq + 1 = next.seq
-- where grp2 = 1;
order by curr.seq
;


+-----+------+-----+------+
| seq | data | grp | grp2 |
+-----+------+-----+------+
|   1 |    1 |  11 |    1 |
|   2 |    0 |  11 |    1 |
|   3 |    0 |  11 |    1 |
|   4 |    0 |  11 |    1 |
|   5 |    2 |  11 |    1 |
|   6 |    2 |  10 |    1 |
|   7 |    1 |   9 |    3 |
|   8 |    0 |   9 |    2 |
|   9 |    0 |   9 |    2 |
|  10 |    1 |   9 |    1 |
|  11 |    0 |   9 |    1 |
|  12 |    0 |   9 |    1 |
|  13 |    2 |   9 |    1 |
|  14 |    0 |   8 |    1 |
|  15 |    0 |   8 |    1 |
|  16 |    0 |   8 |    1 |
|  17 |    0 |   8 |    1 |
|  18 |    0 |   8 |    1 |
|  19 |    2 |   8 |    1 |
|  20 |    2 |   7 |    1 |
|  21 |    1 |   6 |    1 |
|  22 |    0 |   6 |    1 |
|  23 |    0 |   6 |    1 |
|  24 |    0 |   6 |    1 |
|  25 |    2 |   6 |    1 |
|  26 |    2 |   5 |    1 |
|  27 |    0 |   4 |    3 |
|  28 |    1 |   4 |    3 |
|  29 |    0 |   4 |    2 |
|  30 |    0 |   4 |    2 |
|  31 |    0 |   4 |    2 |
|  32 |    1 |   4 |    1 |
|  33 |    0 |   4 |    1 |
|  34 |    0 |   4 |    1 |
|  35 |    0 |   4 |    1 |
|  36 |    0 |   4 |    1 |
|  37 |    2 |   4 |    1 |
|  38 |    0 |   3 |    1 |
|  39 |    0 |   3 |    1 |
|  40 |    0 |   3 |    1 |
|  41 |    0 |   3 |    1 |
|  42 |    0 |   3 |    1 |
|  43 |    0 |   3 |    1 |
|  44 |    0 |   3 |    1 |
|  45 |    0 |   3 |    1 |
|  46 |    2 |   3 |    1 |
|  47 |    2 |   2 |    1 |
|  48 |    2 |   1 |    1 |
+-----+------+-----+------+
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Is it mandatory to have at least two rows, ie one zero?

Comment: @shawnt00 No it isn't, if there's no 0 after 1, just 1 can be a group by itself.

Comment: Ok. I actually just amended my solution to keep all the rows and just add the new column.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks, this approach is awesome. I have a similar problem so I've tried to use the similar approach that you've suggested. I've got what I expected to see but the query is a bit complicated. I've added the example on the question, could you take a look?

Comment: Jenny, I think it's the same. You just need to lag the counter one row in order to include the block-ending row. See update.

Comment: @shawnt00 This is exactly what I wanted to do, thank you so much for the help. This is amazing

Answer (score 1):

Tag the rows twice. First tally the blocks/runs beginning with a 1. Now within each of those, separate and number by runs that start with anything not zero. The "grouped" rows must then be the first ones in the second list.

```
with g1 as (
    select *,
        count(case when data = 1  then 1 end) over (order by seq) as grpA,
        count(case when data = 2  then 1 end) over (order by seq desc) as grpD
    from T
), g2 as (
    select *,
        count(case when data <> 0 then 1 end) over (partition by grpA order by seq) as grpA2,
        count(case when data  = 1 then 1 end) over (partition by grpD order by seq desc
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) + 1 as grpD2
    from g1
)
select seq, data,
    case when grpA2 = 1 then grpA end as groupA,
    case when grpD2 = 1 then grpD end as groupD
from g2;
```

The descending groups are fundamentally the same. Since the stop row is included and triggers the transition, the counter is lagged by a single row and the total is adjusted so that it starts counting at one.

This should be more efficient than self joins.

Answer (score 0):

Using subqueries and `lead` to build the runs of unique `id`s for each valid group of rows:

```sql
with cte as (
   select t.*, (select count(*) from tbl t1 where t1.seq <= t.seq and t1.data > 0) r 
   from tbl t
),
runs as (
   select c.seq, c.data, c.r, case when (c.data = 1 and lead(c.data, 1) over (order by c.seq) = 0) or 
        (c.data = 0 and not exists (select 1 from cte c1 where c1.r = c.r and c1.data > 1)) 
     then c.r else 0 end r1
   from cte c
)
select r.seq, r.data, case when r.r1 = 0 then null else (select count(distinct r1.r1) from runs r1 where r1.seq <= r.seq and r1.r1 > 0) end from runs r
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lm3k9eXm)